# Retrieving the selected item in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I've got a ListFragment with a couple items. I'm trying to implement a longclick
to select an item for some action (edit/delete). Here is what I have in the
ListFragment.

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(itemSelectListener);
}
```

...

```
private AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener itemSelectListener = new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.format("Longclick success! Pos: %d", position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        view.setSelected(true);
        return true;
    }
};
```

So the longclick is working. The list item is correctly highlighted and stays
highlighted. The toast message also shows up with the correct output (for position).

I also tried switching out `view.setSelected(true)` for
`parent.setSelection(position)` with the same result.

But whenever I call `getListView().getSelectedItemId()` or any related method, I
get `null` or garbage integers. I call it from a menu option like so:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case (R.id.action_toast):
            Toast.makeText(
                    getContext(),
                    String.format("ID: %d, POS: %d",
                        getListView().getSelectedItemId(),
                        getListView().getSelectedItemPosition()),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Out of curiosity, I also pasted that call to Toast...show() into
`onItemLongClick` and was met with the same result.

Why isn't this working? It seems so simple.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the list doesn't suppose to have selection, so when you click on a `ListView` item it doesn't change his state to *selected*.

This is why `getListView().getSelectedItemId()` and `getListView().getSelectedItemPosition()` will always return null.

Use the `position` returned in your `LongClickListener` to get your item.

Comment: I thought about just setting a global variable using position, but I need to know whether the item is still selected or not, because the actions have different behavior depending on whether something is selected or not. Anyway, what the heck does `setSelected(true)` do if not to mark the item as selected?